# how to add comma seperated with js sale-count-to money format

Tags: javascript

I want to dispay money format like this **5,000.00** instead of diplaying this code **5000.00**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countto/1.2.0/jquery.countTo.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
$('* .sales-count-to').countTo({
    formatter: function (value, options) {
        return '$ ' + value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, ' ');
    }
});
$('* .count-to').countTo();


<td class="sales-count-to"  data-from="0" data-to="50000" data-speed="1000" data-fresh-interval="20"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Number.toLocaleString()` like in `(+value).toLocaleString('en-US',{minimumFractionDigits:2,maximumFractionDigits:2})`.

The `+` in front of `value` ensures that the variable will be converted to `Number` first (if at all possible).

```js
var value='5000';
console.log((+value).toLocaleString('en-US',{minimumFractionDigits:2,maximumFractionDigits:2}))
```